# Recaptcha Cancelled After Chrome update on 115 version

Tags: javascript, html, apache, google-chrome

We have added a recaptcha on our website. Website was working fine on the chrome till 114 version and captcha is also loading .

After upgrade on 115 captcha load is failed. In the network tab it is showing **(canceled)** as a status.

Trying many option of adding referrer policy, access-control-allow-origin , cors , coop but it still not working.
The same website is working in other browser and lower version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, I came across a situation like this in the browser console--

A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has release new minor version(115.0.5790.110) which has this fix . It was not an issue on application level.